# Class digram to Usecase

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case

I am trying to make a use-case to my project but i have some problem with draw a use case 
Is their any software to convert Class diagram into Use-case?

Comment: Are you aware that these two diagrams are designed to describe different things? Otherwise they could be used fully exchangeably. Also this is offtopic for this site (please read [faq]). More suited place would be probably [programmers.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can can use this softwear visual paradigm  http://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/freeumldesigntool/?src=google&kw=uml%20diagram%20software&mt=p&net=g&plc=&gclid=CJjz79jBi7QCFStgMgodcVEANw

or you can use MS visio  http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/visio/http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/visio/

or see this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools